# Magento 2.3.1 data migration transform field values

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.1

I'm trying to trasform some field values during data migration from Magento 1.9.4.0 to Magento 2.3.1.

In map.xml I added the following:

```
<source>
    - - -
    <field_rules>
       - - -
       <move>
            <field>m_helpdesk_ticket.is_spam</field>
            <to>mst_helpdesk_ticket.folder</to>
        </move>
        <transform>
            <field>m_helpdesk_ticket.is_spam</field>
            <handler class="\Migration\Handler\Convert">
                <param name="map" value="[0:1;1:3;]" />
            </handler>
        </transform>
    </field_rules>
</source>
```

But i get the following error:

```
[2019-06-21 20:20:36][ERROR]: Invalid map provided to convert handler
In Data.php line 126:

  Data Migration failed
```

What I need is:

`m_helpdesk_ticket.is_spam = 0` should be transfered as `mst_helpdesk_ticket.folder = 1`

and

`m_helpdesk_ticket.is_spam = 1` should be transfered as `mst_helpdesk_ticket.folder = 3`

What is wrong in param tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<param name="map" value="[0:1;1:3;]" />
```

the last ";" was wrong, the following is correct:

```
<param name="map" value="[0:1;1:3]" />
```